# triple nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to achieve list comprehension syntax equivalent to the following loops

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

l = list()
for branch in (list1, list2):
    t = list()
    for block in zip(branch[:-1], branch[1:]):
        t.append(block)
    l.append(t)
```

but I am having a hard time coming up with the according comprehension syntax. Can someone help?

Comment: I don't see any list-comprehension in the question... Share your attempt so we can help. Also why the title says triple? I only see two loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest list comprehension as well. Translating literally your for loop, it would be:

```
[[block for block in zip(branch[:-1], branch[1:])] for branch in (list1, list2)]
```

But you can use zip in a better way in this case

```
[list(zip(b, b[1:])) for b in (list1, list2)]
```

Comment: thank you. I just thought that the nesting happens from left to right in comprehensions which is why I tried putting the zip last oO

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension in this way

```py
[list(zip(i, i[1:])) for i in (list1, list2)]
```